# How do I chain consecutive AJAX calls and pass values between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have anonymous ajax function, which edits the response on `success` call. I want to pass the edited response to the next ajax function. Since I want both ajax function to be executed consecutively, I use `.then()`. Inside my first ajax function I edit the response, but when I pass it to the second ajax function, it gets passed unedited. So I guess I am passing the arguments in a wrong way.

Here is my edited code:

**EDIT**

Modified my code as per @Quentin's answer:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var first_request = $.ajax({
    url: 'www.random.com',
    method: 'GET',
  });
  var modified_response = first_request.then(
    function (response) {
      response = response.replace('random', 'SemiRandom');
      return response;  
     });
//here it complains that data is not defined
      modified_response.then(function (data) {
        return $.ajax({
          url: data,
          method: 'GET',
          crossDomain: true,
          xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
          },
          success: function(){
            alert(data);}
      })
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix callbacks and promises. Pick one. Preferably promises.

```
const first_request = 
    $.ajax("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com/");

const modified_response = 
    first_request.then(
        response => response.replace('random', 'semiRandom')
    );

const second_request = 
    modified_response.then(data => $.ajax(data));

const second_response = 
    second_request.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: due to my js version I can not use `=>` symbol

Comment: @sammy333 then just replace `data => ...` with `function(data) { return ... }`  everywhere

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I edited my code based on this answer but I think I just made it worse....

Answer (score 0):

Return the value from first promise success handler to get it in the second function.

Updated code

```
function secondAjax(response){
    $.ajax({
    //here response is still `www.randomURL.com` when I want it to be `www.semiRandomURL.com`
    url: response,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
     //do something
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'www.randomURL.com',
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: false
    },
    success: function(response){
      return secondAjax(response.replace('random', 'semiRandom'));
    }
  });
  }
```

Read more about promise chaining - https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: A `return` in success handler does not pass down promise chain. There is nowhere to return to in `success`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes you are right. I have update the answer

Comment: That doesn't help...nowhere to return to in the click event handler either. Have to change `success` to `then` to use promise chain

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry my bad. Just change the answer. I read the problem different in first read. Anyway thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `success` and add the response argument to the `then()`.

You can also simplify by using `$.get()` shorthand method since the options you appear to be using are all defaults except `crossDomain` which is not really relevant except for testing jsonp requests

```
$.get('www.randomURL.com').then(function(url) {
  url = url.replace('random', 'semiRandom');
  return $.get(url);
}).then(function(results) {
  // do something with results
});
```